# Inline ASM in C, value from array

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, buffer, inline

I need to access value from array in ASM inline. I get segmentation fault from this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
char letters[] = "zbc";
char result; 

    asm("mov (%%ebx), %%eax\n\t"
    :   "=a" (result)
    :   "b"(letters)
    );

printf("%c\n", result);
return 0;

}
```

What's wrong with this code?

And as well, if you could tell me, is it possible to use buffers inline? I need to write inline function in which to all of the letters from array is added some value, and after that new array is returned to C.

Comment: You are probably compiling it as 64 bit code in which case you should use `rbx`.

Comment: That was a problem, thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Is `litery` meant to be `letters`?

Comment: Also, nothing about the code shown appears to *need* to be written in assembly language.  Is this an exercise in assembly programming?  If not, please show the thing you are trying to do that *cannot* be written in C.

Comment: My mistake, yes, littery means letters. Thanks. And yes, this is exercise in asm programming.

Comment: See [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for info.  Specifically, GNU C inline asm is one of the most difficult ways to use asm, esp. for learning asm.

Comment: Note that `mov (%ebx), %eax` will load a 32-bit word from memory, not an 8-bit byte (like the `char`s that make up your array). While this works on x86 (a little-endian architecture where misaligned data is generally permissible), it is probably a bad habit to get into.